# Need a VBA code to place a shape (ex: Down Arrow/Up Arrow ) on top of the specific cell ( based on cell value ) of the table in power point slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need a help in writing a VBA code for placing a shape on cell, based on the cell's value in Power Point table. For suppose if i have a table with 3 rows and 3 Columns in a slide, and my table contains some random numbers in each cell. If the cell value is less than 5, then i want to add or place a down arrow shape ( ↓ ) on top of the cell by using a VBA code.

```
Sub SetTableFont1()
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long

For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
If oShp.HasTable Then

Set oTbl = oShp.Table
For I = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
For J = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Down").Copy
' I have copied a down arrow shape which is manually added in the slide 
  and i named it as "Down"

'Now I am going to select the cells of the table and i want to paste that 
 copied down arrow shape on top of the selected cell.
 oTbl.Cell(J, I).Select
 If oTbl.Cell(J, I).Value <= 5 Then
 oTbl.Cell(J, I).Paste
 End If

 Next J
 Next I
 End If
 Next oShp
 Next oSld
 End Sub

 Please help me on above code.
 Below is screenshot for Reference
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONHme.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pasting into a cell isn't going to work. Theoretically, you could get the table's position and dimensions, then create a 2D array of row widths and column heights. Then after finding the target cell, calculate its position and set the arrow to those co-ordinates. However, if any cells are merged or subdivided, you'll get an incorrect result, as there isn't any easy way to identify those in VBA.